# How do the sleeping automatons of "You're All Alone" recover from the changes made by the Awakened?

Tags: fritz-leiber

I recently got a chance to read *You're All Alone* by Fritz Leiber. The basic premise of the book is that Carl MacKay deviates slightly from his usual schedule and finds that the world is now operating slight out of sync with people reacting to words he might have normally said. As the novella progresses, and the more actions he takes off-script, the more out-of-sync he's getting. It's indicated that there are other Awakened people and most of them are treating the rest of humanity as dolls to be used and discarded. One would expect small changes to rapidly expand into much larger deviations, causing the system to break down, and yet the effects always seem localized. Some of the reviews refer to "resets", but I saw nothing of the sort. How does the world recover?

I have heard that this was expanded into a full-length novel named *The Sinful Ones*. Was this resolved in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one else has made input on this, my theory is that the script is set at the beginning of the day, upon waking. There was a point made partway through *You're All Alone* where Carr Mackay is told by Jane Gregg that, if he wants to try to forget, the easiest way is by sleeping longer, preferably through use of sleeping pills and alcohol, befuddling the memory and making it easier to get back on-script, awaking with the new state of affairs and adapting it into our narrative as necessary. It works further as a metaphor for how so many of us lose ourselves to the uncaring machinery of life when we turn to such drugs as a way to dull our senses.

This does, I suppose, presuppose some sort of force nudging things back into place, although, if the roles are deeply ingrained within each person, it is possible that the only aspect of thought that most people exercise is finding ways to excuse the inconsistencies and make them fit the narrative, sort of a "Sunnydale Syndrome" as seen in the Buffy the Vampire Slayer series.

I will welcome any other theories on the subject, of course.